# Convert/represent multiple time series to/as ONE

Tags: time-series, u8darts

Let say I have multiple sensors that generate time series data .
Is there a way to represent/convert/compress them as a SINGLE data time series.

I can imagine several ways :

```
- sum them
- average them
- FFT them, pick the top frequencies and then recombine them
- ...
```

Is there standard approaches ?